# How to compare multiple tables using minus operator or joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I have files which load into 3-5 tables from source. Before they used to come from a specific source, now they moved into cloud systems. I have to load and compare the old source data and the one comes from cloud.Ideally they should be matching.

I created a backup table for old source data and then compared it with new one using minus operator. It works. But there is some files that land to 3-4 tables and the table structures are different, it’s too much work to do one by one. I want to know how I can compare multiple tables using minus query with joins?
Thanks in advance!

```
Select * from tbl1
Minus
Select *from tbl2
```

Comment: You have also the option of "where not exists()", but the key question is how much columns you need to compare in case the PK was not preserved in the migration. Also be aware that SET operations may become very costly in term of memory consumption.

Comment: can you please send us the  table structures and  some sample data as in your question you asked "some files that land to 3-4 tables and the table structures are different, "

Comment: You'll have to write joins to reassemble the data so both sources are comparable. That requires knowing the data and how it's been restructured.

Answer (score 0):

So, tbl1 minus tbl2 will give what differs in tbl1 from what is found in tbl2, but will not give what is found in tbl2 and is not found in tbl1. Therfore, to find all the differences:

```
with dif1 as (
  select * from tbl1
  minus 
  select * from tbl2
)
,dif2 as (
  select * from tbl2
  minus
  select * from tbl1
)
select 'T1' tabx, * from dif1
union all
select 'T2' tabx, * from dif2
;
```

Or, were it to be a join, then it should be a full outer join. A full outer may help you see in the same row the columns from tbl1 and those from tbl2 corresponding to the join condition. It depends on what you really need.

Comment: `join` have a major drawback for such task: it cannot compare nulls easily. To perform set comparisons set operators are the best tool: either double minus or union with `group by <all columns>` and conditional count.

Comment: When using join, in order to actually avoid comparing nulls, you may compare the hash value for a concatenated list of columns, like: standard_hash(col1||'|'||to_char(col2_d,'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss)'||'|'||...||'|'||col_n, 'SHA512') or eventually use ora_hash, which may eventually lead to collisions or dbms_utility.get_hash_value. The main problem for join would be that both tables have a primary key and that the join is on the primary key columns.

Comment: I assume all the columns as a key for comparison because we need to identify tuple differences. If we are comparing on a "key" basis (subset of columns) then it will add more complexity: identifying unique key. `minus` works well regardless of the key columns